# how can I run shell script file in linux?

Tags: bash, shell

i have a problem in running linux script (.sh) file. The file is as given below:
you can find all folders, files and code at [dosbios-master](https://github.com/p-durlej/dosbios).
the script file is as given below.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

asm() {
nasm -o $2 $1
}

asm bios/dosbios.asm bios/dosbios.sys

asm boot/mboot.asm  boot/mboot.bin
asm boot/boot.asm   boot/boot.com

asm util/format.asm util/format.com
asm util/fdisk.asm  util/fdisk.com
asm util/reboot.asm util/reboot.com
asm util/mem.asm    util/mem.com
asm util/attrib.asm util/attrib.com

#dd if=/dev/null of=dosbios.sys bs=512 seek=9

export MTOOLSRC=mtools.cfg

perl -e 'print chr(0xf6) x 2880 x 512' > disk/newdos.tmp

mformat -m 0xf8 -v DOS  a:
mcopy   bios/dosbios.sys a:io.sys
mcopy   msdos/msdos.sys a:
mcopy   msdos/*.com a:
mcopy   msdos/*.exe a:
mcopy   msdos1/*.com    a:

mcopy   util/*.com  a:
mcopy -a legal/*    a:
mcopy -a etc/*      a:

mattrib -a +s +h +r a:io.sys
mattrib -a +s +h +r a:msdos.sys

dd status=none if=boot/boot.com of=disk/newdos.tmp 
conv=notrunc

mv disk/newdos.tmp disk/newdos.img
```

how can I run this shell script in linux. i tried double click, then ./genimage, then "bash genimage.sh". but i couldn't succeed.
how should I run this script file, and which environment or by which command.
or by using which tool?

Comment: What happens when you try? Is the file set as runnable?

Comment: try       chmod +x <script name>

Comment: however, bash <script name> should have worked. What is the error that you get ? maybe script exits somehow, probably in nasm. Could you put an echo inside asm()

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
~$ chmod +x genimage

~$ ./genimage
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it